# How do I stop event invites from a particular group without leaving it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-events

I'm a member of a group on Facebook. I want to unsubscribe from event invites without leaving the group. Is this possible?

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deal with unwanted notifications on Facebook is to click the three dots to the right of the notification on web or swipe left on mobile app and click "more", it will give you option to "Turn off event notifications from this page", "Turn off notifications about this event", etc.

Comment: This will not stop event invites.

Comment: @serenesat I actually don't have any group event notifications to play with (only pages), what options do you see when following my above instructions? You don't see something like "Turn off event notifications from this group"?

Comment: This option seems to have been removes from that menu.  Is it still possible to unsubscribe from event notifications without unsubscribing from other notifications?